# NSTextView + NSTextFinder + my separate NSSearchField

Tags: cocoa, search, nstextview, nssearchfield

I am trying to implement searching in NSTextView with search query coming from my custom NSSearchField.

Sounds pretty simple, but I cannot get it working.

So far I've looked through all the Apple Documentation about `NSTextFinder`, its client and FindBarContainer. The TextFinder simply provides the FindBarView to the container, and container shows it when you activate searching.

All the communication between the client, container and TextFinder is hidden. It just looks like a black-box that is designed to work "as is" without any customisation or interference.

But what about `- (void)performAction:(NSTextFinderAction)op` method of NSTextFinder? Isn't it for sending custom commands to the TextFinder?

I was trying to assign a new search string to it with the following:

```
    NSPasteboard* pBoard = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:NSFindPboard];
    [pBoard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSPasteboardTypeString, NSPasteboardTypeTextFinderOptions, nil] owner:nil];
    [pBoard setString:_theView.searchField.stringValue forType:NSStringPboardType];
    NSDictionary * options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSTextFinderCaseInsensitiveKey,
                              [NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSTextFinderMatchingTypeContains], NSTextFinderMatchingTypeKey,
                              nil];

    [pBoard setPropertyList:options forType:NSPasteboardTypeTextFinderOptions];

    [textFinder performAction:NSTextFinderActionSetSearchString];
```

but that doesn't work and simply breaks the normal findBar operation.

I have a strong feeling that I am doing something wrong.
All I want is to have a standard search functionality in my own NSSearchField. Is that possible?

I bet I am not the first one who is not happy with normal findBar.

Your help is very needed and appreciated!

Comment: Please note, that the creating custom SearchField is not a problem. I am stuck with implementing the searching mechanism for the NSTextView that would allow using my custom SearchField.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope. Ended up using default Find Bar. But will have to return to this back pretty soon.

Comment: You might find this useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46817490/how-to-use-nstextfinder-programmatically/46892350?noredirect=1#comment80745309_46892350

Answer (score 1):

For an NSTextView, NSTextFinder is mostly just a user interface for NSString's [func range(of searchString: String, options mask: NSString.CompareOptions = [], range rangeOfReceiverToSearch: NSRange) -> NSRange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1415073-range)

If you want to implement your own search on an NSTextView, use that. To search forward, you construct a range starting at the end of the current selections's range and going to the end of the NSTextView's text. To search backward, construct a range starting at 0 and going to the beginning of the current selection's range, and tell NSString to use backwards search.

If NSString returns a `.notFound` range, implement wrap-around yourself.

If you need `startsWith`, `endsWith` or `wholeWord` you'll need to take the result NSString's func gives you, check to see if it will do, and if not adjust the range and call it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSComboBox`. Return search value using below delegate:

```
- (NSString *)comboBox:(NSComboBox *)aComboBox completedString:(NSString *)substring
{    
    if ([aComboBox tag] == 101 || [aComboBox tag] == 102) {
        NSArray *currentList;
        if ([aComboBox tag] == 101) {
            NSArray *keyArray = keySuggestions;
            currentList = keyArray;
        } else {
            currentList = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.valueSuggestions];
        }
        NSEnumerator *theEnum = [currentList objectEnumerator];
        id eachString;
        NSInteger maxLength = 0;
        NSString *bestMatch = @"";
        while (nil != (eachString = [theEnum nextObject])) {
            NSString *commonPrefix = [eachString
                                      commonPrefixWithString:substring options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if ([commonPrefix length] >= [substring length] && [commonPrefix
                                                                length] > maxLength)
            {
                maxLength = [commonPrefix length];
                bestMatch = eachString;
                break;
            }
        }
        return bestMatch;
    }

    return substring;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But that doesn't answer my question. The problem is not in the SearchField. I want to implement an easy way to search the TextView with my custom search field. Using NSTextFinder would be nice. But if it is impossible, please provide some other working solution.