# How to use NSTextFinder programmatically?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview

I'd like to do a "find" operation in an `NSTextView` without using the built-in find bar. How can I programmatically set a search string and have the results highlighted inside the text view?

This is for macOS 10.12 and higher.

FWIW, this is not a duplicate of this question: [NSTextFinder set search string and clear visual feedback programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839265/nstextfinder-set-search-string-and-clear-visual-feedback-programatically)

That question is about programmatically controlling the find bar UI, either clearing previous find results or populating the find bar search field.

This question is about invoking a "find" operation programmatically without using the find bar UI at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSTextFinder set search string and clear visual feedback programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839265/nstextfinder-set-search-string-and-clear-visual-feedback-programatically)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. Please see edit.

Comment: First set the search string, then call `performAction:`.

Comment: How do I set the search string programmatically? I tried by putting it into the Find Pasteboard as in the other question and then calling `[textFinder performAction:NSTextFinderActionSetSearchString]`, but the NSTextFinder doesn't use my string unless I show the find bar UI. If I don't show the find bar, the previously set search string will still be used.

Comment: Ok, not a copy, the answer doesn't work. I'll have a try.

Comment: I can't let `NSTextFinder` search without a find bar but it is possible to hide the bar. Create a `NSTextFinder`, set `client` to the `NSTextView` and `findBarContainer` to a controller which implements `NSTextFinderBarContainer`. Put the findBar in a hidden view. To search, find the searchfield, set the stringValue and call `sendAction:to:`. `usesFindBar` of the text view is true.

Comment: Do you have sample code you could share? I'm having trouble with this: "To search, find the searchfield, set the stringValue and call `sendAction:to:`." How do I find the searchField and what is the receiver and parameters for `sendAction:to:`? My `NSTextFinderBarContainer` is just a view subclass that declares the required properties and has an empty implementation of `findBarViewDidChangeHeight`. Is that enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my test code (hacky, experimental):

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong) NSTextFinder *textFinder;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextView *textView; // find Uses Bar, Incremental Searching is on
@property (weak) NSView *myFindBarView;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSView *findBarContainerView; // hidden
@property BOOL barVisible;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textFinder = [[NSTextFinder alloc] init];
    self.textFinder.incrementalSearchingEnabled = YES;
    self.textFinder.incrementalSearchingShouldDimContentView = YES;
    self.textFinder.client = (id<NSTextFinderClient>)self.textView;
    self.textFinder.findBarContainer = self;
    [self.textFinder performAction:NSTextFinderActionShowFindInterface];
}

- (IBAction)testSearchString:(id)sender {
    // action method of a Test button, searches for "found"
    [self.textFinder cancelFindIndicator];

    // search the subviews for a view of class NSSearchField
    __block __weak NSSearchField *(^weak_findSearchField)(NSView *);
    NSSearchField *(^findSearchField)(NSView *);
    weak_findSearchField = findSearchField = ^(NSView *view) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[NSSearchField class]])
            return (NSSearchField *)view;
        __block NSSearchField *foundView = nil;
        [view.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSView *subview, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {  
            foundView = weak_findSearchField(subview);
            if (foundView)
                *stop = YES;
        }];
        return foundView;
    };

    NSSearchField *searchField = findSearchField(self.myFindBarView);
    [searchField setStringValue:@"found"];
    // execute the action of the search field to confirm the new value and do a search
    [searchField sendAction:searchField.action to:searchField.target];
    /* add to select all
    [self.textFinder performAction:NSTextFinderActionSelectAll];
    */
}

// NSTextFinderBarContainer

- (void)findBarViewDidChangeHeight {
}

- (NSView *)findBarView {
    return self.myFindBarView;
}

- (void)setFindBarView:(NSView *)theView {
    self.myFindBarView = theView;
    if (theView) {
        NSRect frame = theView.frame;
        frame.size.width = self.findBarContainerView.bounds.size.width;
        theView.frame = frame;
        [self.findBarContainerView addSubview:theView];
    }
}

- (NSView *)contentView {
    return self.textView.enclosingScrollView.contentView;
}

- (BOOL)isFindBarVisible {
    return self.barVisible;
}

- (void)setFindBarVisible:(BOOL)theVisible {
    self.barVisible = theVisible;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks. This got me pointed in the right direction and now I can play around with it. It didn't occur to me to recursively search the findBar for the searchField in order to populate it. Do you know what the `NSTextFinderAction` `NSTextFinderActionSetSearchString` does? I thought that was the way to set the search string, but couldn't figure out how to provide a search string as an argument.

Comment: `NSTextFinderActionSetSearchString` does Use Selection for Find (Command-E).